# AVAudiorecorder & AVAudioPlayer not always playing sound

Tags: avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I have a view in which I record sound using `AVAudiorecorder` and then it save to the document directory. And from another View I am playing the sound using `AVAudioplayer` from document directory. But the strange behavior is that `AVaudioPlayer` always not playing the sound, but in sometimes it play sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the problem is solved, I have to reinitialize the audio session to playbackCategory using the following code

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

Now it can always play the sound.

Comment: Hey mondal, can you please help me as I think I have the same problem.
Where do you execute the above code?

Thanks

Comment: Before the the AVAudioplayer initialization for play the sound add the above code. Hope it will solve your problem.